# Cicleplus symbol in MATLAB figure

Tags: matlab

I want to insert a text to the MATLAB figure which has 'circleplus' symbol, (a plus in the circle, https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePlus.html).
Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: MATLAB supports LaTeX code in figure annotation.

Comment: indeed it does.. this has somehow escaped me - thanks a lot!

Comment: however it looks like cicrcleminus (\ominus in latex) is not supported ?

Comment: \ominus works on my computer, matlab r2015b

Comment: You might have to change the text's `interpreter` to `'latex'`.

Comment: Or just `char(8853)` for the [Unicode circled plus character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2295/index.htm).

Comment: thanks guys, both `$\ominus$` with `'Interpreter', 'latex'` option and `char(8853)` worked. I actually prefer the second option, as using the latex interpreter removes some text formatting.